# How to obtain such minified code with unreadable variables and constructs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this snippet of minified code, it's apparent that variable names and constructs are not human-readable. How can one obtain such code, and is it possible to transform it into a more readable format?

```
! function() {
"use strict";

function t(e) {
    return function(t) {
        return n = typeof(t = t), (null === t ? "null" : "object" == n && (Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(t) || t.constructor && "Array" === t.constructor.name) ? "array" : "object" == n && (String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(t) || t.constructor && "String" === t.constructor.name) ? "string" : n) === e;
        var n
    }
}
var o, B = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.PluginManager"),
    I = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.util.VK"),
    u = t("string"),
    a = t("array"),
    K = function(t) {
        return o === t
    }, z = n("boolean"),
    j = n("function"),
    s = function() {}, V = function(t, n) {
        return t === n
    }, l = i(!1),
    c = i(!(o = null)),
    f = {
        fold: function(t, n) {
            return t()
        },
        isSome: l,
        isNone: c,
        getOr: e,
        getOrThunk: m,
        getOrDie: function(t) {
            throw new Error(t || "error: getOrDie called on none.")
        },
        getOrNull: i(null),
        getOrUndefined: i(void 0),
        or: e,
        orThunk: m,
        map: r,
        each: s,
        bind: r,
        exists: l,
        forall: c,
        filter: function() {
            return f
        },
        toArray: function() {
            return []
        },
        toString: i("none()")
    };
```

Comment: To get meaningful variable names you'd either need to change the variable names yourself or get the original source code from whoever has that code.  (Assuming the *original* source code itself even has meaningful variable names.)

Answer (score 0):

If its an external lib you included, maybe there are [source maps](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps/) for you to use. Most javascript code nowadays gets processed through different build steps like transpiling, obfuscation and minification. The reason being build size, stripping of logs and debug messages, security through obfuscation, different not browser native languages in the build chain that are going to translate back to html, javascript and css in the end. If you want to achieve this obfuscation step yourself, look into [this resource](https://kinsta.com/blog/minify-javascript/).

You can use tools like uglify or yui compressor (or, if you have a build pipeline with gulp or webpack in place, they provide tools for this as well).

Source Maps are some files on your webserver, with information for chrome debugger so that he is able to de-minify and de-uglyfie your production ready code without changing the js dist files.

Comment: Source map may also contain the full original source code used to generate the obfuscated version.